# Pre-chat Link Task and Contact

Tags: contact, tasks, liveagent, pre-chat

I am trying to link a contact to a Task, but I can't seem to do that on the pre chat form. Any help would be greatly appreciated. From what I have read online this should work. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">
<!-- This script takes the endpoint URL parameter passed from the deployment
page and makes it the action for the form -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    function handlePageLoad() {
      var endpointMatcher = new RegExp("[\\?\\&]endpoint=([^&#]*)");
    document.getElementById('prechatForm').setAttribute('action', decodeURIComponent(endpointMatcher.exec(document.location.search)[1]));
    } 
    if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('load', handlePageLoad, false);
    } else { 
      window.attachEvent('onload', handlePageLoad, false);
    }})();
</script>


<h1>Pre-chat Form</h1>
<form method='post' id='prechatForm'>
    First name: <input type='text' name='liveagent.prechat:FirstNameDetail' id='customFieldFName' /><br />
    Last name: <input type='text' name='liveagent.prechat:LastNameDetail' id='customFieldLName' /><br />
    Email: <input type="text" name="liveagent.prechat:EmailDetail" id='customFieldEmail'/><br />
    Policy Number: <input type="text" name="liveagent.prechat:taskSubject" /><br />

    <!-- Map liveagent.prechat:FirstNameDetail, liveagent.prechat:LastNameDetail, and liveagent.prechat:EmailDetail
         custom detail to Contact's field FirstName, LastName, and Email -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Contact" value="FirstName,FirstNameDetail;LastName,LastNameDetail;Email,EmailDetail" />

    <!-- Specify to query for a matching Contact records Email field based on the value of the contacts Email -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Contact" value="Email,true" />

    <!-- Return results only if there is an exact match of the Email -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Contact" value="Email,true" />

    <!-- If no match in search, create a new Contact record with the mapped value of firstname, lastname, and email -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Contact" value="FirstName,true;LastName,true;Email,true" />

    <!-- If a new Contact record has been created, open it as a subtab -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Contact" value="true" />

    <!-- Save the Contact on the Live Chat Transcript's Contact Loookup -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Contact" value="Contact" />

    <!-- Create a Task every time -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Task" value="Subject,taskSubject;Name,ContactId;" />
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Task" value="Subject,true;Name,true;" />
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Task" value="Task" />
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Task" value="true" />

    <!-- Link the Contact to the Case -->
    <input type= "hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.linkToEntity:Task" value="Task,ContactId;" />

    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Contact" value="Contact" />


    <input type='submit' value='Request Chat' id='prechat_submit'/>
    <style type="text/css">
    p {font-weight: bolder }
    </style>
</form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: So what is your question? Are you getting any error message?

Comment: I get no errors and it makes the task and contact, but it doesn't link the two. I was wondering if anyone saw something I was doing wrong at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change ContactId to WhoId.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that should work:

```
<!-- Link the Contact to the Task -->
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.linkToEntity:Contact" value="Task,WhoId" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this because you can't relate the task to a record that doesn't exist yet. I would solve this by passing a hidden value to the contact and have a trigger in the contact object to create the task automatically based on that value, which in your case seems to be the Policy Number.

Comment: That makes sense, I just find it so weird you can do it for a Case, but not a Task.